# Setting Activity in my ViewPager

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hi everybody I have a ViewPager I want a Setting Activity in, but I can not do it because is a Activity and not a fragment, could I do it?

I want something like this:

http://tjerktech.files.wordpress.com/2012/06/spotify1.png

And there is some code that I have:

```
PagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;
List<Fragment> fragments = new Vector<Fragment>();

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_days_routine);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    //String nameRoutine = getIntent().getExtras().getString("nameRoutine");

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the activity.
    for(int i= 0;i<5;i++){
        fragments.add(Fragment.instantiate(this, Activity.class.getName()));
    }

    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(this.getSupportFragmentManager(), fragments);

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(
                actionBar.newTab()
                        .setText(getResources().getString(R.string.tab_day) + " " +(i+1))
                        .setTabListener(this));
    }
}
```

Comment: Would use of the PreferenceFragment do the trick?

Comment: I did not know that PreferenceFragment exists, I will check it out, thanks!

Comment: That not work in API 7 :/, I was seeking for something that works in old android version

Comment: You'll have to use the PreferenceActivity for older versions (that don't have the PreferenceFragment). :)

Comment: Also, I'm not 100% sure what you mean with settings - settings as in "Options", or something else? :-)

Comment: I want that interface in my ViewPager, and to do it I must use PreferenceFragment but I cant use it because is not supported by android old versions like API 7

Comment: I'm not sure `PreferenceFragment` is the thing you're looking for, as the screenshot itself is showing a bunch of list items with headers (not settings). :)

Comment: That doesnt work to me, I use API 7, anyway I solved it with a ListView about this tutorial http://bartinger.at/listview-with-sectionsseparators/

Comment: @Richy - Where you able to achieve this ??